# SSL Encryption and an external image server

Tags: html, ssl

I have an ASP.NET web site technology that I use for scores of clients.  Each client gets their own web site (a copy of the core site that can then be customized).  The web site includes a fair amount of content - articles on health and wellness - that is loaded from a central content server.  I can load the html for these articles from a central content server by copying from the content server and then inserting the text into the page as it is produced.

Easy so far.

However, these articles have image references that point back to the central server. The problem that I have is due to the fact that these sites are always accessed (every page) via an SSL link.  When a page with an external image reference is loaded, the visitor receives a message that the page "contains both secure and insecure elements" (or something similar) because the images come from the (unsecured) server.  There is really no way around this.

So, in your judgment, is it better to:

A) just put a cert on the content server so I can get the images over SSL? Are there problems there due to the page content having two certs?  Any other thoughts?

B) change the links to the article presentation page so they don't use SSL? They don't need SSL but the left side of the page contains lots of links to pages that do need - all of which are now relative links.  Making them all absolute links is grody because each client's site has its own URL so all links would need to be generated in code (blech).

C) Something else that I haven't thought of?  This is where I am hoping that someone with experience in the area will offer something brilliant!

**NOTE:** I know that I can not get rid of the warning about insecure elements - it is there for a reason.  I am just wondering if anyone else has experience in this area and has a reasonable compromise or some new insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a completely different way to import the images late last night after asking this question.  In IIS, at least, you can set up "Virtual Directories" that can point essentially anywhere (I'm now evaluating whether to use a dedicated directory on each web server or a URL).  If I use a dedicated directory on each server I will have three directories to keep up to date, but at least I don't have 70+.

Since each site will pull the images using resource locations found on the local site, then I don't have to worry about changing the SSL status of any page.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how feasable this is but it may be possible to use a *rewrite* or *proxy* module to mirror the (img directory) structure on each clone to that of the central. With such a rule in place you could use relative img urls instead & internally rewrite all requests to these images over to the central server, silently

e.g.:

```
https://cloneA/banner.jpg -> http://central/static/banner.jpg
https://cloneB/topic7/img/header.jpg -> http://central/static/topic7/header.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with B.

Sadly, I think you'll find this is a sad fact of life in SSL. Even if you were to put a cert on the other server, I think it may still get confused because of different sites [can't confirm nor deny though], and regardless, you don't want to waste the time of your media server by encrypting images.